# Using Sinon to test after promise resolution

Tags: javascript, promise, mocking, sinon, spy

I have some code that executes after a promise is resolved. I'm trying to spy on a method that should be invoked post-promise resolution but I'm having problems with my tests finishing execution before the call to the spied on method is invoked.

How can I test the call to `storage.add` is actually being made?

Here's the test:

```
"it marks true in storage": function() {
    sinonSandbox.stub(tested, "updateServiceApi", function() {
        return MPromise.resolve();
    });

    var storageStub = sinonSandbox.stub(storage, "add");

    tested._execute();

    expect(
        storageStub.calledWith("name", true)
    ).to.be.true
}
```

And here's the implementation:

```
_execute: function() {
    this.updateServiceApi().then(function(){
        // tests finish before this code is executed :(
        storage.add("name", true);
    });
},
```

Comment: What test runner are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you've written your test as if `_execute` is synchronous.

Because of the promises, the `expect` call will be executed before the `storage.add()` call is made.

Exactly how you deal with this will be test runner dependent, but the general fix is to add a `.then()` to the called function in the test which will contain your `expect` code.

```
"it marks true in storage": function() {
    sinonSandbox.stub(tested, "updateServiceApi", function() {
        return MPromise.resolve();
    });

    var storageStub = sinonSandbox.stub(storage, "add");

    return tested._execute()
        .then(() => {
             expect(storageStub.calledWith("name", true)).to.be.true;
        });
}
```